# List of class objects

Tags: java

I'm stuck.. I trying to parse a text from file in words, but save it in List of objects. Whether it is possible to do so?

```
    public class Text {
    public static List<Words> words = new ArrayList<Words>();
}

public class Words {

private String path;
private String[] inside;
private BufferedReader in;

public Words(String path, String[] inside) {
    this.inside = inside;
    this.path = path;
}

public String[] splittinIntoWords() throws IOException {

    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String s;

    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        inside = s.split(" ");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inside)); 
    }
    return inside;
}

}
```

and main class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String file_name = "book.doc";
    String[] inside = null;
    Words w = new Words(file_name, inside);
    w.splittinIntoWords();

    Text.words.add(w); //after add in list i have a reference.
    System.out.println(Text.words.toString());
}
}
```

i do smthg wrong. I understand how to do this with List of Strings 
tell me please, it is possible, to add text splitting into words in List of Words

Answer (score 0):

You’re overwriting the array of words `Words.inside` with each line you read. You need to add the output of `split()` to a List every time round the while loop, not just at the end.

I would expect your code to display the words in the last line of your file, but possibly it has a blank last line, in which case you will see nothing.

Also, I assume your "book.doc" is not really a .doc format file—word processor files need special parsing; what you have written will only work on plain text files.

Answer (score 0):

there is several things wrong with your code.

1. Text.words shouldn't be static. Every instance of text consists of a different collection of words.
2. When you make a "Collection of Words", then it should be Collection< Word>. Because every item inside the collection is just a single item.
3. but then again, Collection< Word> is just the same as Collection< String>. So use that.
4. "path", "in" should not be member variables of "Words". Just use them locally in your method. Especially since you never closed "in".
5. you're overwriting whatever is in "inside" for each line in your file that you loop over. When you have your "Collection< String> words", then just do words.addAll(inside); in
   your loop.

Yes, I know this is not an answer, but I'm trying to point you in the right direction. This might help you more in the long run.